# iCal - can a TimeZone TZID parameter contain a ":" char?

Tags: c++, char, timezone, icalendar, malformed

In a c++ project, I'm writing a parser to read from and write to .ics files. To do that, I test my parser against several files with a maximum of possible cases, from several sources (gmail, yahoo, ...). Recently I found in a test file a situation that leaves me a little confused, and for which I could not find a satisfactory answer.

One of my test file failed to be imported by my parser. The VEVENT that cause the issue contains the following start date:

```
DTSTART;TZID=GMT+04:00:20120103T120000
```

This event match with a VTIMEZONE, that declares his TZID parameter as follow:

```
TZID:GMT+04:00
```

AFAIK the ":" char should be instead used as separator, and I suspect that the VTIMEZONE itself is malformed in the sample described above, but I  didn't find any document that explicitly specifies that this situation can never happen. I also noticed that several apps like Thunderbird also fail to import this file, apparently for the same reason.

So my question is: can a TZID parameter in a VTIMEZONE contain a ":" char?

Also, I don't know if I should use the TZID content as a key to extract the ISO date from the DTSTART parameter, or if I do simply reject a such event, tagging it as corrupted, and showing an error message after the importation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The authority on this is RFC5545 and the relevant subsections:
[RFC5545 3.2.19.  Time Zone Identifier](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.2.19)

> tzidparam  = "TZID" "=" [tzidprefix] paramtext

which is complemented by
[RFC5545 3.1.  Content Lines](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.1)

> param         = param-name "=" param-value *("," param-value)
> param-value   = paramtext / quoted-string
> paramtext     = *SAFE-CHAR
> [..]
> SAFE-CHAR     = WSP / %x21 / %x23-2B / %x2D-39 / %x3C-7E
> / NON-US-ASCII
> ; Any character except CONTROL, DQUOTE, ";", ":", ","

From which we can conclude that a Time Zone ID parameter **cannot** contain a ":" char.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it is indeed what I suspected